# Receiving an error InvalidOperationException when posting to an api ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm getting an error when i'm calling a method that post to an api and provide push notifications from my api. I'm receiving the error "InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending." Here is the code for my post to api

```
public static async void postToPushNotifcationAsync(String deviceId, String message, String title)
{
    var fcm = new FCMJsonModel();
    var fcmNotification = new FCMNotificationModel();

    fcmNotification.body = message;
    fcmNotification.title = title;
    fcmNotification.sound = "sound.caf";
    fcm.to = deviceId;
    fcm.notification = fcmNotification;

    var json = fcm.ToJSON();

    var content = new StringContent(json);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new
    System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


    //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    var response = await
    client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", content,
    cts.Token);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I declare my httpclient as a global class variable since I have to use this method multiple times.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Comment: Your method is async void. Try returning a `Task` instead and await the result of this method call, because the `response` will no longer be available if you return to the client before the task is complete.

Comment: @ps2goat I changed the return to Task<string> and i'm returning it now and when I call the method I do var result = await postToNotification(methods) and then it made my api to async. Is a WEB API async fine? I'm still getting an error about bad request which never happened before.

Comment: async web api controllers are fine, as long as you are awaiting any async functions you call before returning.  Can you post the controller code, too?  The smallest amount  that recreates the issue is fine. And if you have a stack trace that you don't mind posting, that will also help.

Comment: @Joy have you tried without specifying the cancellation token?
    `var response = await
    client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", content);`